# What is the closest translation for the word "biākharīna" in Quran 4:133?

Tags: quran-translation

In [Yusuf Ali's English translation](http://transliteration.org/quran/WebSite_CD/MixYuwsuf/Fram2E.htm), the word "biākharīna" is interpreted as meaning "race" as indicated below.

004.133 If it were His will, He could destroy you, o mankind, and create another **race**; for He hath power this to do.    إِ‌ن‌ْ يَشَأْ‌ يُذْهِ‍‍بْ‍‍كُمْ ‌أَيُّهَا‌ ‌ال‍‍‍نّ‍‍‍َاسُ ‌وَيَأْتِ بِآ‍‍‍‍خَ‍‍‍ر‍ِ‍ي‍‍نَ ۚ ‌وَك‍‍َانَ ‌اللَّ‍‍هُ عَلَى ذَلِكَ قَ‍‍دِي‍‍ر‌اً

However, in the [Quranic Corpus](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=4&verse=133), it is interpreted as "others".

Does it mean "race" or does it mean "others" or something else?  What is the closest translation/interpretation?  Does the word have similar meanings elsewhere in the Quran?

Comment: To clarify - I'm no fan of the Yusuf Ali translation, but the word "race" here refers to the archaic definition of race that we would now call species - i.e. the human race.

Comment: @Prometheus thank you, I had an intuition that one of the possible meanings was replacement our species, Homo Sapiens (wise man???), with one with one that attained a more perfected evolution of social intelligence; say Homo Benedictus (Benevolent Man).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word "آخَر" simply means "other." It can be used just like you would use the word "other" in English. Sometimes, it would also be translated as "another."

"آخَرُون" and "آخَرِين" are simply plurals of that meaning "others."

The simplest way to translate the phrase in verse 4:33 would be:

> ‌وَيَأْتِ بِآ‍‍‍‍خَ‍‍‍ر‍ِ‍ي‍‍نَ
>
> And bring others.

The translation only added the word "race" as a bit of an elaboration because in this context "others" can be interpreted as "another race."

The word "آخَرِين" is used earlier in the same Surah in verse 4:91 if you wish to look. It's a common word, so it is used many times in the Quran.